# how to use avg in order by clause in sql

Tags: mysql

Hi I'm just new to sql and having some trouble with this problem.
I'm sorting table subjcode by ascending order of average score and the descending order of passed-rate.
and the code is

```
select * 
from subjcode 
group by sno 
order by(select avg(score) from subjcode group by sno)asc ;
```

and it never worked it alwats says errorcode:1242.

the following table is named subjcode:

```
Sno     cno     score
S001    C001    78.90
S001    C002    82.90
S001    C003    59.00
S002    C001    80.90
S002    C002    72.90
S003    C001    81.90
S003    C002    81.90
S004    C001    60.90
```

please can someone help me?thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to put the `AVG()` in another `SELECT`. Just:

```
ORDER BY AVG(score)
```

But it doesn't make sense to use `SELECT *` when you're grouping. All the other columns will be selected from random rows in the group. You should just do:

```
SELECT sno, AVG(score) AS avg
FROM subjcode
GROUP BY sno
ORDER BY avg
```